# Validation of Data on SPSS

Tags: spss, dataset, validation

I have the data of 150 participants [2 different methods that assess the same thing (Blood pressure), one of which is considered as "gold standard method"] and I want to validate them on individual and group level.
My questions are:
for the group-level validation is a paired t-test ok?
for the individual-level validation (where my main problem is) should I do a cross-classification? divide the participants into quintiles?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by group-level.

Comment: I have to validate one method over the other (which is the criterion method) by taking into consideration the whole group of 150 participants.

Comment: A t-test or robust alternatives would do.

Comment: and checking the difference and the mean of the 2 different methods?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question...

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "validation" of methods?  Is one of them a "gold standard" of known quality to which you want to compare the second, as suggested by the term "validation"?  Or are you merely comparing their results, as suggested by your proposed use of a paired t-test?  Or something else?  And please explain what a "cross-classification" might be and how it would help accomplish a validation, whatever you might mean by that. (To limit the potential for confusing answers, I have closed this question in the meantime.)

Comment: Yes. The one method is the "gold standard method"

Comment: Regarding the cross-classification, it was a question to be honest as I am not sure how can I validate a method at an individual level. (As I mentioned I have a sample of 150 participants)